# How do I see the answers or comments that I have made?

Tags: discussion, comments, user-interface, user-experience

Under *activity* I want to see comments and replies that I have made, not those addressed to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your profile select the *Activity* tab.

Then select *All actions* in the tabs under your profile box.

Then [select *Comments*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=comments).

[image: “Activity” tab → “All actions” tab → “Comments” tab]